# Object Detection model_main.py error: Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I am trying to get the model_main.py file working for a custom object detector I am creating. I seem to be running into the following error however, and can't figure out how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

I am running the following command:

```
sudo python3 /data/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=/data/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco.config —model_dir=/home/USER/TASK/models/faster_rcnn_resnet50_coco/ --num_train_steps=200000 --num_eval_steps=1500 --sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=1 --alsologtostderr
```

The error is as follows:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 1. First element had shape [600,900,3] and element 1 had shape [512,1024,3].
```

The full traceback is at https://pastebin.com/SktxTnix

I believe the issue to lie with the image_resizer in the config file. Possibly my images are too large, causing issues with shuffle buffer running out of memory? I am unable to remedy this however by changing the min and max resize values.

EDIT: After some more playing around, I do not believe this is an issue with the buffer size. I reduced it down further to 512MB, which filled fine, and still received the same error, see: https://pastebin.com/e2TBwvWd

Comment: It seems I get the same. could it be solved? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I was not able to figure out the issue sadly. If you have any luck please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried padding? Not sure, why previous versions worked without it.

```
 keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
```